# FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask

Tags: cassandra, hive, datastax-enterprise, datastax

I am using datastax 4.5 and at one node i have enabled hadoop and spark.
Now when i executing query in hive shell i an getting error

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to instantiate
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient

Please suggest what i am missing.

Thanks

Comment: Can you run the following command to attach more debugging log to this question? bin/dse hive -hiveconf hive.root.logger=Debug,console

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.RuntimeException:Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22711364/java-lang-runtimeexceptionunable-to-instantiate-org-apache-hadoop-hive-metastor)