# Hive 2.1.1 MetaException(message:Version information not found in metastore. )

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

I'm running Hadoop 2.7.3, MySQL 5.7.17 and Hive 2.1.1 on Ubuntu 16.04.

When I run ./hive, I keep getting the following warning and exception:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/server/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/server/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/home/server/hive/lib/hive-common-2.1.1.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
Mon Feb 13 12:01:41 EST 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Mon Feb 13 12:01:41 EST 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Mon Feb 13 12:01:41 EST 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Mon Feb 13 12:01:41 EST 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Mon Feb 13 12:01:42 EST 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Mon Feb 13 12:01:42 EST 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Mon Feb 13 12:01:42 EST 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Mon Feb 13 12:01:42 EST 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<init>(Hive.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.create(Hive.java:310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getInternal(Hive.java:290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:266)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:558)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1654)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3367)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3406)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3386)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:3640)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:221)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1652)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: MetaException(message:Version information not found in metastore. )
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.checkSchema(ObjectStore.java:7753)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.verifySchema(ObjectStore.java:7731)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.invoke(RawStoreProxy.java:101)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.verifySchema(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:565)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:626)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:6490)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:70)
    ... 28 more
```

Here is my hive-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
 <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
 <configuration>

     <property>
         <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
         <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
     </property>


     <property>
         <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
         <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
     </property>

     <property>
         <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
         <value>hive</value>
     </property>

     <property>
         <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
         <value>password</value>
     </property>

 </configuration>
```

In order to fix the error, I've tried [Hive Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41939582/hive-unable-to-instantiate-org-apache-hadoop-hive-ql-metadata-sessionhivemetasto) and [Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35449274/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-org-apache-hadoop-hive-ql-meta). But I am still getting the same exceptions.

I'm newbie to Hadoop and Hive, how could I fix the exception?
Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The necessary tables required for the metastore are missing in MySQL. Manually create the tables and restart hive metastore.

The schema files for MySQL will be available under the path `$HIVE_HOME/scripts/metastore/upgrade/mysql/`.

```
cd $HIVE_HOME/scripts/metastore/upgrade/mysql/

< Login into MySQL >

mysql> drop database IF EXISTS hive;
mysql> create database hive;
mysql> use hive;
mysql> source hive-schema-2.1.1.mysql.sql;
```

Restart Hive metastore.

Comment: Thanks franklinsijo, it works! Do you know how to eliminate those warnings, too?

Comment: That rises from MySQL. Try replacing the connecting string as `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=tr‌​ue&useSSL=false` or set it to `true` and provide SSL certificate.

Comment: useSSL=false solves the warning issues. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 14):

I have faced the similar issue. The issue can be solved by initializing Metastore Schema using below command for Mysql

> **schematool --dbType mysql --initSchema**

this command can be used for any Metastore => replace dbType "mysql" with the "Metastrore used for hive"

for more info--> https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Schema+Tool

Comment: this may fail if metastore_db already exists, so rm -rf metastore_db before doing this

Answer (score 2):

there is a tool provided by hive to upgrade hive database :

```
./bin/schematool -dbType derby -upgradeSchemaFrom 2.1.0
```

bests

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue when i was setting up HIVE 2.3.1 for the first time.
I am using postgres database as a metastore.

Then i had to set the below property to false.

```
  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.schema.verification</name>
    <value>false</value>
    <description>
      Enforce metastore schema version consistency.
      True: Verify that version information stored in is compatible with one from Hive jars.  Also disable automatic
            schema migration attempt. Users are required to manually migrate schema after Hive upgrade which ensures
            proper metastore schema migration. (Default)
      False: Warn if the version information stored in metastore doesn't match with one from in Hive jars.
    </description>
  </property>
```

Comment: SET hive.metastore.schema.verification property to false in hive-site.xml

Answer (score 0):

fllow belows ,that  will make sence

I have faced the similar issue. The issue can be solved by initializing Metastore Schema using below command for MySQL

```
schematool --dbType mysql --initSchema
```

this command can be used for any Metastore => replace dbType "mysql" with the "Metastrore used for hive"

for more info--> https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Schema+Tool

Answer (score 0):

I copied all the jars in the `hadoop\share\hadoop\hdfs` and `hadoop\lib` folder and placed them in the `hive\lib` folder

Now everything is working fine

and then I ran

```
hive --service metastore
```

Then I run
`hive`