# Install Hive-2.1.1 on Mac os got error of ‘Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient’

Tags: mysql, apache, hadoop, hive

I am installing HIVE-2.1.1 on Mac os with Hadoop-2.8.0 installed. I followed the instruction of https://dtflaneur.wordpress.com/2015/10/04/installing-hive-on-osx-el-capitan/ to install hive. I can do first 5 steps without error. I configured hive-site.xml as

```
<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
    <value>hiveuser</value>
    <description>Username to use against metastore database </description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
    <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
    <description>
  JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore.
  To use SSL to encrypt/authenticate the connection, provide database-specific SSL flag in the connection URL.
  For example, jdbc:postgresql://myhost/db?ssl=true for postgres database.
    </description>
</property>
<property>
   <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
   <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
   <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>
<property>
   <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
   <value>hiveuser</value>
   <description>Username to use against metastore database</description>
</property>
<property>
   <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
   <value>welcome1</value>
   <description>password to use against metastore database</description>
</property>
<property>
   <name>datanucleus.fixedDatastore</name>
   <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>hive.exec.local.scratchdir</name>
   <value>/tmp/hive</value>
   <description>Local scratch space for Hive jobs</description>
</property>
<property>
   <name>hive.downloaded.resources.dir</name>
   <value>/tmp/hive</value>
   <description>Temporary local directory for added resources in the remote file system.</description>
</property>
<property>
   <name>hive.querylog.location</name>
   <value>/tmp/hive</value>
   <description>Location of Hive run time structured log file</description>
 </property>
```

When I run $hive, I got error of Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient. The full error is like below. I tried grant privileges by :

```
<code>
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON*.* TO 'hiveuser'@'%' Identified by 'welcome1';  
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON*.* TO 'hiveuser'@'localhost' Identified by 'welcome1';  
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON*.* TO 'hiveuser'@'127.0.0.1' Identified by 'welcome1';  
</code>
```

and using Mysql user 'root'

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE metastore;
mysql> USE metastore;
mysql> GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,ALTER,CREATE ON metastore.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
```

and correspondingly change the ConnectionUserName to root, and ConnectionPassword to welcome1 in the hive-site.xml file. The hive-site.xml file I post is the one I change the user name back to hiveuser. Because It still doesn't work when I change user to root.

Please help me to solve it! Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The error is post here:

Comment: this solved for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42209875/hive-2-1-1-metaexceptionmessageversion-information-not-found-in-metastore

Answer (score 0):

The error is post here:
 SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/hive/2.1.1/libexec/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.8.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
    SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]

```
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/hive/2.1.1/libexec/lib/hive-common-2.1.1.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
2017-06-16T12:18:24,547  INFO [main] SessionState: 
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/hive/2.1.1/libexec/lib/hive-common-2.1.1.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
2017-06-16T12:18:24,550 DEBUG [main] conf.VariableSubstitution: Substitution is on: hive
2017-06-16T12:18:24,819 DEBUG [main] lib.MutableMetricsFactory: field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableRate org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.loginSuccess with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(about=, always=false, sampleName=Ops, type=DEFAULT, value=[Rate of successful kerberos logins and latency (milliseconds)], valueName=Time)
2017-06-16T12:18:24,828 DEBUG [main] lib.MutableMetricsFactory: field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableRate org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.loginFailure with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(about=, always=false, sampleName=Ops, type=DEFAULT, value=[Rate of failed kerberos logins and latency (milliseconds)], valueName=Time)
2017-06-16T12:18:24,828 DEBUG [main] lib.MutableMetricsFactory: field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableRate org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.getGroups with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(about=, always=false, sampleName=Ops, type=DEFAULT, value=[GetGroups], valueName=Time)
2017-06-16T12:18:24,828 DEBUG [main] lib.MutableMetricsFactory: field private org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableGaugeLong org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.renewalFailuresTotal with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(about=, always=false, sampleName=Ops, type=DEFAULT, value=[Renewal failures since startup], valueName=Time)
2017-06-16T12:18:24,829 DEBUG [main] lib.MutableMetricsFactory: field private org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableGaugeInt org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.renewalFailures with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(about=, always=false, sampleName=Ops, type=DEFAULT, value=[Renewal failures since last successful login], valueName=Time)
2017-06-16T12:18:24,832 DEBUG [main] impl.MetricsSystemImpl: UgiMetrics, User and group related metrics
2017-06-16T12:18:25,024 DEBUG [main] security.Groups:  Creating new Groups object
2017-06-16T12:18:25,029 DEBUG [main] util.NativeCodeLoader: Trying to load the custom-built native-hadoop library...
2017-06-16T12:18:25,031 DEBUG [main] util.NativeCodeLoader: Failed to load native-hadoop with error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no hadoop in java.library.path
2017-06-16T12:18:25,031 DEBUG [main] util.NativeCodeLoader: java.library.path=/Users/xchen011/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
2017-06-16T12:18:25,031  WARN [main] util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2017-06-16T12:18:25,033 DEBUG [main] util.PerformanceAdvisory: Falling back to shell based
2017-06-16T12:18:25,035 DEBUG [main] security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback: Group mapping impl=org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping
2017-06-16T12:18:25,041 DEBUG [main] security.Groups: Group mapping impl=org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback; cacheTimeout=300000; warningDeltaMs=5000
2017-06-16T12:18:25,047 DEBUG [main] security.UserGroupInformation: hadoop login
2017-06-16T12:18:25,048 DEBUG [main] security.UserGroupInformation: hadoop login commit
2017-06-16T12:18:25,053 DEBUG [main] security.UserGroupInformation: using local user:UnixPrincipal: xchen011
2017-06-16T12:18:25,053 DEBUG [main] security.UserGroupInformation: Using user: "UnixPrincipal: xchen011" with name xchen011
2017-06-16T12:18:25,053 DEBUG [main] security.UserGroupInformation: User entry: "xchen011"
2017-06-16T12:18:25,054 DEBUG [main] security.UserGroupInformation: Assuming keytab is managed externally since logged in from subject.
2017-06-16T12:18:25,055 DEBUG [main] security.UserGroupInformation: UGI loginUser:xchen011 (auth:SIMPLE)
2017-06-16T12:18:25,160  INFO [main] metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: Opening raw store with implementation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
2017-06-16T12:18:25,236 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding datanucleus.storeManagerType value null from  jpox.properties with rdbms
2017-06-16T12:18:25,236 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding datanucleus.schema.validateConstraints value null from  jpox.properties with false
2017-06-16T12:18:25,238 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding datanucleus.autoStartMechanismMode value null from  jpox.properties with ignored
2017-06-16T12:18:25,239 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding datanucleus.fixedDatastore value null from  jpox.properties with false
2017-06-16T12:18:25,239 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding datanucleus.schema.validateTables value null from  jpox.properties with false
2017-06-16T12:18:25,240 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding javax.jdo.option.Multithreaded value null from  jpox.properties with true
2017-06-16T12:18:25,240 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding datanucleus.rdbms.initializeColumnInfo value null from  jpox.properties with NONE
2017-06-16T12:18:25,240 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding datanucleus.cache.level2.type value null from  jpox.properties with none
2017-06-16T12:18:25,240 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding datanucleus.connectionPoolingType value null from  jpox.properties with BONECP
2017-06-16T12:18:25,241 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName value null from  jpox.properties with hiveuser
2017-06-16T12:18:25,242 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding datanucleus.schema.autoCreateAll value null from  jpox.properties with false
2017-06-16T12:18:25,242 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding javax.jdo.option.NonTransactionalRead value null from  jpox.properties with true
2017-06-16T12:18:25,243 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding datanucleus.transactionIsolation value null from  jpox.properties with read-committed
2017-06-16T12:18:25,243 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL value null from  jpox.properties with jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
2017-06-16T12:18:25,246 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding datanucleus.schema.validateColumns value null from  jpox.properties with false
2017-06-16T12:18:25,246 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding datanucleus.identifierFactory value null from  jpox.properties with datanucleus1
2017-06-16T12:18:25,246 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass value null from  jpox.properties with org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory
2017-06-16T12:18:25,246 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding datanucleus.cache.level2 value null from  jpox.properties with false
2017-06-16T12:18:25,246 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding datanucleus.rdbms.useLegacyNativeValueStrategy value null from  jpox.properties with true
2017-06-16T12:18:25,255 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding hive.metastore.integral.jdo.pushdown value null from  jpox.properties with false
2017-06-16T12:18:25,258 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding javax.jdo.option.DetachAllOnCommit value null from  jpox.properties with true
2017-06-16T12:18:25,258 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName value null from  jpox.properties with com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
2017-06-16T12:18:25,258 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding datanucleus.plugin.pluginRegistryBundleCheck value null from  jpox.properties with LOG
2017-06-16T12:18:25,318 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: datanucleus.schema.autoCreateAll = false
2017-06-16T12:18:25,318 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: datanucleus.schema.validateTables = false
2017-06-16T12:18:25,318 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: datanucleus.rdbms.useLegacyNativeValueStrategy = true
2017-06-16T12:18:25,318 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: datanucleus.schema.validateColumns = false
2017-06-16T12:18:25,318 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: hive.metastore.integral.jdo.pushdown = false
2017-06-16T12:18:25,318 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: datanucleus.autoStartMechanismMode = ignored
2017-06-16T12:18:25,318 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: datanucleus.rdbms.initializeColumnInfo = NONE
2017-06-16T12:18:25,318 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: javax.jdo.option.Multithreaded = true
2017-06-16T12:18:25,318 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: datanucleus.identifierFactory = datanucleus1
2017-06-16T12:18:25,318 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: datanucleus.transactionIsolation = read-committed
2017-06-16T12:18:25,318 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL = jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
2017-06-16T12:18:25,319 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: javax.jdo.option.DetachAllOnCommit = true
2017-06-16T12:18:25,319 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: javax.jdo.option.NonTransactionalRead = true
2017-06-16T12:18:25,319 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: datanucleus.fixedDatastore = false
2017-06-16T12:18:25,320 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
2017-06-16T12:18:25,320 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: datanucleus.schema.validateConstraints = false
2017-06-16T12:18:25,321 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName = hiveuser
2017-06-16T12:18:25,321 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: datanucleus.cache.level2 = false
2017-06-16T12:18:25,322 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: datanucleus.plugin.pluginRegistryBundleCheck = LOG
2017-06-16T12:18:25,322 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: datanucleus.cache.level2.type = none
2017-06-16T12:18:25,322 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass = org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory
2017-06-16T12:18:25,322 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: datanucleus.storeManagerType = rdbms
2017-06-16T12:18:25,322 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: datanucleus.connectionPoolingType = BONECP
2017-06-16T12:18:25,323  INFO [main] metastore.ObjectStore: ObjectStore, initialize called
2017-06-16T12:18:26,174 DEBUG [main] bonecp.BoneCPDataSource: JDBC URL = jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true, Username = hiveuser, partitions = 1, max (per partition) = 10, min (per partition) = 0, idle max age = 60 min, idle test period = 240 min, strategy = DEFAULT
Fri Jun 16 12:18:26 EDT 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Fri Jun 16 12:18:26 EDT 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Fri Jun 16 12:18:26 EDT 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Fri Jun 16 12:18:27 EDT 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
2017-06-16T12:18:27,278  INFO [main] metastore.ObjectStore: Setting MetaStore object pin classes with hive.metastore.cache.pinobjtypes="Table,StorageDescriptor,SerDeInfo,Partition,Database,Type,FieldSchema,Order"
2017-06-16T12:18:29,123 DEBUG [main] bonecp.BoneCPDataSource: JDBC URL = jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true, Username = hiveuser, partitions = 1, max (per partition) = 10, min (per partition) = 0, idle max age = 60 min, idle test period = 240 min, strategy = DEFAULT
Fri Jun 16 12:18:29 EDT 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Fri Jun 16 12:18:29 EDT 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Fri Jun 16 12:18:29 EDT 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Fri Jun 16 12:18:29 EDT 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
2017-06-16T12:18:29,207 DEBUG [main] metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql: Direct SQL query in 7.514296ms + 0.088517ms, the query is [SET @@session.sql_mode=ANSI_QUOTES]
2017-06-16T12:18:29,253  WARN [main] metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql: Self-test query [select "DB_ID" from "DBS"] failed; direct SQL is disabled
javax.jdo.JDODataStoreException: Error executing SQL query "select "DB_ID" from "DBS"".
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:543)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.executeInternal(JDOQuery.java:388)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.execute(JDOQuery.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql.runTestQuery(MetaStoreDirectSql.java:240)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql.<init>(MetaStoreDirectSql.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initializeHelper(ObjectStore.java:404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:336)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:297)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:58)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:599)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:564)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:626)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:6490)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1652)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3367)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3406)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3386)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:3640)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<init>(Hive.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.create(Hive.java:310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getInternal(Hive.java:290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:266)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:558)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:234)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:148)
NestedThrowablesStackTrace:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'metastore.dbs' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1966)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.PreparedStatementHandle.executeQuery(PreparedStatementHandle.java:174)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ParamLoggingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ParamLoggingPreparedStatement.java:375)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.SQLController.executeStatementQuery(SQLController.java:552)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.SQLQuery.performExecute(SQLQuery.java:645)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeQuery(Query.java:1844)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.SQLQuery.executeWithArray(SQLQuery.java:807)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.execute(Query.java:1715)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.executeInternal(JDOQuery.java:371)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.execute(JDOQuery.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql.runTestQuery(MetaStoreDirectSql.java:240)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql.<init>(MetaStoreDirectSql.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initializeHelper(ObjectStore.java:404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:336)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:297)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:58)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:599)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:564)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:626)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:6490)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1652)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3367)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3406)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3386)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:3640)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<init>(Hive.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.create(Hive.java:310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getInternal(Hive.java:290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:266)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:558)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:234)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:148)
2017-06-16T12:18:29,260 DEBUG [main] metastore.ObjectStore: RawStore:
```