# In the apache-drill web console, i am able to enable all the plugins but except that hive plugin

Tags: apache-drill

I am newbie to Apache Drill.

I am querying hive using apache drill. So, i have to enable that plugin in the web console
When i click on hive enable plugin option in the web console, immediately it is throwing exception in the terminal [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYtuC.png):. please help me to solve this issue.

Look at that all the plugins are enabled in the web console except that hive [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlAek.png):

below is my hive-site.xml file [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jB1xB.png):

How do I start Apache Drill correctly?

Comment: I looked for `Version information not found in metastore` and found this helpful page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42209875/hive-2-1-1-metaexceptionmessageversion-information-not-found-in-metastore

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you performed 
**schematool -dbType derby -initSchema** for Hive metastore 2.1 version (or above) before enabling Drill's Hive storage plugin: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Schema+Tool

Actually adding **datanucleus.schema.autoCreateAll true** and **hive.metastore.schema.verification: false** properties to your plugin could help you, but it is not recomended for production purposes:
https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/common/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/conf/HiveConf.java#L974

Note: The default values for them depends on the version of Hive you are using.

If you configure Hive metastore properly, the configs from Apache Drill docs should work for you:
https://drill.apache.org/docs/hive-storage-plugin/#hive-remote-metastore-configuration

Comment: what steps you have mentioned, I followed that  but still i am getting the same exception in the terminal.

Comment: Can you perform Hive queries via Hive CLI? What version of Hive do you use? Please share plugin configs, which you are using.

Comment: yeah i am performing queries on hive CLI. i am using hive version 2.3.3.

Comment: What version of Drill are you using? You should use Drill1.13 to work with Hive2.3.3.  Also please do share plugin configs from your 3 reference in the post.

Comment: Yeah i am using drill 1.13 to work with hive2.3.3. To know the actual problem, i installed haddop and drill in another system.I got to know that even without installing hive i just run drill in embedded mode. I am getting that same issues like all plugins are enabled but except that hive plugin. plugins like mongodb, hbase etc..are not installed in my system but they are enabling in apache drill web console.  i am not understanding why it is like that?can you please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: This is the other issue. All plugins are disabled by default (except cp and dfs). In the process of updating plugins configs the templates for them are used. There is a bug when a client is created for some storage even when plugin is disabled. 

But client for Hive can't be created due to some checks inside the HiveMetaStoreClient. You can find more details here: issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-6412


But "hive.metastore.schema.verification": "false" property in the Drill Hive storage plugin configs can solve this issue (as workaround).

Comment: I assume that it should help you too. If it doesn't, please post your plugin configs that you use for Hive storage plugin.