# Hive 2.3.3 MetaException(message:Version information not found in metastore. )

Tags: hadoop, hive, hive-metastore

I have Hive 2.3.3 and Hadoop 3.1.0.
I can start Hive with the hive comand on terminal, but when i try to create a table i receive the following error:

```
    user$ hive
readlink: illegal option -- f
usage: readlink [-n] [file ...]
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/caiocesare/Desktop/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.6.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/caiocesare/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/Users/caiocesare/Desktop/hive/lib/hive-common-2.3.3.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
Hive-on-MR is deprecated in Hive 2 and may not be available in the future versions. Consider using a different execution engine (i.e. spark, tez) or using Hive 1.X releases.
hive> CREATE TABLE pokes (foo INT, bar STRING);
FAILED: SemanticException org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
hive>
```

if i start hive --service metastore the code below is the error posted:

```
user$ hive --service metastore
  readlink: 
  illegal option -- f
  usage: readlink [-n] [file ...]
2018-05-08 11:20:50: Starting Hive Metastore Server
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/caiocesare/Desktop/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.6.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/caiocesare/Desktop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
MetaException(message:Version information not found in metastore. )
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:83)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:6887)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:6882)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.startMetaStore(HiveMetaStore.java:7140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.main(HiveMetaStore.java:7067)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:308)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:222)
Caused by: MetaException(message:Version information not found in metastore. )
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.checkSchema(ObjectStore.java:7564)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.verifySchema(ObjectStore.java:7542)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.invoke(RawStoreProxy.java:101)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.verifySchema(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMSForConf(HiveMetaStore.java:591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:584)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:651)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:427)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invokeInternal(RetryingHMSHandler.java:148)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:79)
    ... 11 more
Exception in thread "main" MetaException(message:Version information not found in metastore. )
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:83)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:6887)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:6882)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.startMetaStore(HiveMetaStore.java:7140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.main(HiveMetaStore.java:7067)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:308)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:222)
Caused by: MetaException(message:Version information not found in metastore. )
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.checkSchema(ObjectStore.java:7564)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.verifySchema(ObjectStore.java:7542)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.invoke(RawStoreProxy.java:101)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.verifySchema(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMSForConf(HiveMetaStore.java:591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:584)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:651)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:427)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invokeInternal(RetryingHMSHandler.java:148)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:79)
    ... 11 more
```

The only modification i have done, following my university teacher guide, is to delete hive-jdbc-1.0.0-standalone.jar and create the /tmp and /user/hive/warehouse. Someone can help me to use hive?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hive 2.1.1 MetaException(message:Version information not found in metastore. )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42209875/hive-2-1-1-metaexceptionmessageversion-information-not-found-in-metastore)

Comment: i saw it but there are a differente stack of error message.

Comment: Can you post your `hive-site.xml`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution by myself.
i'll post it:
following the command on the link below.
[Hive schema tool](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Schema+Tool)

After that you'll receive, when you try to open hive an Error-like: metastore use a differente schematool version.
For that i used: 
Therefore follow below steps and modify database like MySql as per your requirement:

```
Before you run hive for the first time, run

schematool -initSchema -dbType derby
If you already ran hive and then tried to initSchema and it's failing:

mv metastore_db metastore_db.tmp
Re run

schematool -initSchema -dbType derby
Run hive again
```

Also if you change directories, the metastore_db created above won't be found.
It worked for me.

Comment: Please, accept your own answer to make others know that this question is resolved.