# Running HIVE command throwing error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, bigdata

I have done the HIVE setup on my Ubuntu machine as per this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hive/hive_installation.htm).
When I run HIVE command (the last step), I get this exception:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/administrator/apache-hive-2.1.1-bin/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/administrator/hadoop-2.7.1/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/home/administrator/apache-hive-2.1.1-bin/lib/hive-common-2.1.1.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:591)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:531)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:705)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:226)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<init>(Hive.java:366)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.create(Hive.java:310)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getInternal(Hive.java:290)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:266)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:558)
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of :-
[java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35449274/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-org-apache-hadoop-hive-ql-meta)

It seems that you are using derby database for the metastore.  I had also faced similar problems on vm.

If you can, please install mysql and use that for metastore.

For more info :-

https://dzone.com/articles/how-configure-mysql-metastore

Answer (score 0):

From the property, it will create only the database but not the schema. Try creating the schema required for Hive metastore in MySQL

cd $HIVE_HOME/scripts/metastore/upgrade/mysql/
 < login to mysql using command (mysql -u root -p) where root is the username and password will be asked>

```
 mysql> use metastore;
 mysql> source hive-schema-<your_version>.mysql.sql;
```

e.g source hive-schema-2.1.0.mysql.sql;
Then restart hive metastore process using.
hive --service metastore.
Hopefully, this will solve the problem!