# Could not access hive cli

Tags: hadoop, hive

i have installed hadoop and hive on the centos 7 machine, i am unable to access hive cli.

```
[centos@ip-10-103-2-173 hive]$ hive

    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using the ParNew young collector with the Serial old collector is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
    WARNING: Use "yarn jar" to launch YARN applications.
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using the ParNew young collector with the Serial old collector is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
    17/02/27 14:17:24 WARN conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.metastore.pre-event.listeners does not exist
    17/02/27 14:17:24 WARN conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.metastore.local does not exist
    17/02/27 14:17:24 WARN conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.optimize.mapjoin.mapreduce does not exist
    17/02/27 14:17:24 WARN conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.auto.convert.sortmerge.join.noconditionaltask does not exist
    17/02/27 14:17:24 WARN conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.semantic.analyzer.factory.impl does not exist

    Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/conf/hive-log4j.properties
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:677)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:621)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

please help. I am using postgresql.

Comment: Does your hive lib have all the hadoop jars in it ? Also, is your hadoop working fine?

Comment: Possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35449274/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-org-apache-hadoop-hive-ql-meta/35594597

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)