# What is the alternate of inferschema in Spark 2.0 or above

Tags: pyspark

What is the alternate of inferschema in Spark 2.0 or above ? I am unable execute sqlContext.inferschema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from spark documentation , inferSchema is deprecated in version 1.3, use `createDataFrame()` instead.

Comment: Thanks Pushkar , however I am getting error in pyspark installed in windows machine with below query -                              
    orderItemsSchema = sqlContext.createDataFrame(orderItems)      ----------Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o785.applySchemaToPythonRDD.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35449274/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-org-apache-hadoop-hive-ql-meta#35594597