# unable run commands in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

new to Hive, connected to hive console and ran

```
hive> show tables;
FAILED: HiveException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
hive>
```

what does this error mean? how do you fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35449274/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-org-apache-hadoop-hive-ql-meta

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35449274/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-org-apache-hadoop-hive-ql-meta)

Comment: @GaurangShah, this answer uses mysql. I dont have mysql, I just need to use hive. Is that possible?