# Getting error 'Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient' while running spark.sql query

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, pyspark

I am trying to run  a simple command

```
spark.sql('SELECT * FROM df).show()
```

I am getting this error

```
AnalysisException: 'java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient;'
```

I just started learning spark a few days back and don't understand what is causing this error. Please help.

What steps need to be followed to stop this exception?

Comment: Possible duplicated with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35449274/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-org-apache-hadoop-hive-ql-meta

Comment: @DuyNguyenHoang yes I saw that ..but couldn't understand what to do...as I have already mentioned, I have just started learning Spark...and don't have enough expertise to understand the solution in the link you gave... Can you please help in any other way?

Comment: Could you please post more code about your implementation to see inside? And also spark config