# All hive commands in hive console give an exception

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am running windows 10, hadoop 2.8.5 and hive 2.3.5. I installed Hive while following this guide:

https://kontext.tech/docs/DataAndBusinessIntelligence/p/apache-hive-300-installation-on-windows-10-step-by-step-guide

Each command in hive console ends with this exception after a while:

`hive> show tables;
FAILED: SemanticException org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient`

Before anyone points out this is a duplicate question, none of the other solved my problem, namely:

[question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35449274/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-org-apache-hadoop-hive-ql-meta)
[question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35449274/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-org-apache-hadoop-hive-ql-meta)

and others that I do not have links for at the moment. This is what I did:

1. run hadoop by using `start-all.cmd`, this works fine.
2. in cygwin, I created the metastore `schematool -dbType derby -initSchema`. Again, this finishes fine.
3. run hive server: `hive --service hiveserver2 start`
4. start hive console: `hive`

All of these work, but no command in hive console finishes. My .bashrc for cygwin:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_212"
export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
export HADOOP_HOME='/cygdrive/c/hadoop-2.8.5'
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
export HIVE_HOME='/cygdrive/c/hive-2.3.5'
export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$HIVE_HOME/lib/*.jar
```

I have tried generating schema anew many times, and even setting the path in hive-site.xml in `javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL` setting, and starting hive from HIVE_HOME and other directories, to no avail. I have run out of ideas as to what to try next.