# AnalysisException: 'java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I have `spark-2.3.3-bin-hadoop2.7` downloaded from https://spark.apache.org/. I am using `Jupyter Notebook` to run pyspark.ml code, but sadly it gives me an error that it cannot instantiate: apache hadoop.hive

I saw a similar problem here  [java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35449274/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-org-apache-hadoop-hive-ql-meta) ,but the people there said I need to create `hive-site.xml` I don't know where I am supposed to do this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~/server/spark-2.3.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o209.load.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.externalCatalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog$lzycompute(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder$$anon$1.<init>(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.analyzer(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$build$2.apply(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$build$2.apply(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.analyzer$lzycompute(SessionState.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.analyzer(SessionState.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.baseRelationToDataFrame(SparkSession.scala:432)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.TextInputCSVDataSource$.createBaseDataset(CSVDataSource.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.TextInputCSVDataSource$.infer(CSVDataSource.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVDataSource.inferSchema(CSVDataSource.scala:63)


AnalysisException: 'java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient;'
```

Please, tell me if anyone knows where that file should be placed or another alternative solution to the problem

Comment: Here's where you'll find the answer: "hive-default.xml.template is located in the conf directory in your installation root, and hive-site.xml should also be created in the same directory." https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+Configuration

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously the problem was that I am using the default hive metastore embedded derby. I used the code below and the problem disappeared.

rm   metastore_db/*.lck