# Databricks metastore error - Connection reset

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, metastore

Upon my Databricks setup in Azure cloud, first i am trying to execute below query in my ADB Notebook,

**spark.sql("CREATE CATALOG IF NOT EXISTS QUICKSTART_CATALOG")**

But i'm getting below error. Could not able to fix, full error log shared below?
Any issue in my databricks setup or anything missing here?

**Error**
java.lang.Exception: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: **java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient**   at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.$anonfun$withClient$2(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:163)   at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.maybeSynchronized(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:115)   at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.$anonfun$withClient$1(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:153)   at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ProgressReporter$.withStatusCode(ProgressReporter.scala:390)    at com.databricks.spark.util.SparkDatabricksProgressReporter$.withStatusCode(ProgressReporter.scala:34)     at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:152)  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:313)  at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:263)  at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:253)     at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.externalCatalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:62)  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.$anonfun$resourceLoader$1(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:69)    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionResourceLoader.client$lzycompute(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:167)     at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionResourceLoader.client(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:167)    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionResourceLoader.$anonfun$addJar$1(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:171)     at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionResourceLoader.$anonfun$addJar$1$adapted(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:170)     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionResourceLoader.addJar(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:170)    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.AddJarsCommand.$anonfun$run$1(resources.scala:38)     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.AddJarsCommand.$anonfun$run$1$adapted(resources.scala:36)     at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.foreach(Stream.scala:533)  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.AddJarsCommand.run(resources.scala:36)    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:80)    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:78)   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:89)     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$2(QueryExecution.scala:229)  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$8(SQLExecution.scala:249)   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:399)   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:194)   at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:985)     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:148)  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:349)  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:229)  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$QueryExecution$$withMVTagsIfNecessary(QueryExecution.scala:214)     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:227)     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:220)     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:512)     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:99)     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:512)    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:298)    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:294)   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:488)   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1(QueryExecution.scala:220)    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:354)  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:220)   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:174)   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:165)  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:239)     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.$anonfun$ofRows$2(Dataset.scala:108)   at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:985)     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:105)  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.$anonfun$sql$1(SparkSession.scala:820)     at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:985)     at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:815)    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:695)    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.$anonfun$new$6(DriverLocal.scala:279)   at org.apache.spark.SafeAddJarOrFile$.safe(SafeAddJarOrFile.scala:31)   at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.$anonfun$new$5(DriverLocal.scala:279)   at com.databricks.sql.acl.CheckPermissions$.trusted(CheckPermissions.scala:1808)    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.$anonfun$new$4(DriverLocal.scala:278)   at com.databricks.unity.UCSEphemeralState$Handle.runWith(UCSEphemeralState.scala:41)    at com.databricks.unity.HandleImpl.runWith(UCSHandle.scala:99)  at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.$anonfun$new$3(DriverLocal.scala:271)   at scala.util.Using$.resource(Using.scala:269)  at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.$anonfun$new$2(DriverLocal.scala:270)   at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)   at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)   at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)     at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)     at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.<init>(DriverLocal.scala:257)     at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocalBase.<init>(PythonDriverLocalBase.scala:168)     at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.JupyterDriverLocal.<init>(JupyterDriverLocal.scala:381)   at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverWrapper.instantiateDriver(DriverWrapper.scala:723)  at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.setupRepl(DriverWrapper.scala:342)    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:231)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getDatabase(Hive.java:1169)  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.databaseExists(Hive.java:1154)   at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.Shim_v0_12.databaseExists(HiveShim.scala:619)   at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.$anonfun$databaseExists$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:440)  at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)   at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.$anonfun$withHiveState$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:337)   at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.$anonfun$retryLocked$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:236)     at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.synchronizeOnObject(HiveClientImpl.scala:274)    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.retryLocked(HiveClientImpl.scala:228)    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.withHiveState(HiveClientImpl.scala:317)  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.databaseExists(HiveClientImpl.scala:440)     at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.PoolingHiveClient.$anonfun$databaseExists$1(PoolingHiveClient.scala:321)    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.PoolingHiveClient.$anonfun$databaseExists$1$adapted(PoolingHiveClient.scala:320)    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.PoolingHiveClient.withHiveClient(PoolingHiveClient.scala:149)   at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.PoolingHiveClient.databaseExists(PoolingHiveClient.scala:320)   at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.$anonfun$databaseExists$1(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:313)   at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)   at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:80)  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.$anonfun$withClient$2(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:154)   ... 79 more Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1412)    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:62)   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:72)   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:2453)    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:2465)   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getDatabase(Hive.java:1165)  ... 97 more Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: null    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor836.newInstance(null)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1410)    ... 102 more Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: Error creating transactional connection factory    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:671)   at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:830)  at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:334)  at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:213)     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor322.invoke(null)  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)  at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)  at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)     at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701)     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:331)    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:360)     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:269)    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:244)   at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:79)  at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:139)     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:58)   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:67)   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:497)    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:475)  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:523)    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:397)   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.<init>(HiveMetaStore.java:356)   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:54)     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:59)     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:4944)    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:171)  ... 106 more Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: null   at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor894.newInstance(null)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)  at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:606)     at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:330)   at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.registerConnectionFactory(AbstractStoreManager.java:203)  at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.<init>(AbstractStoreManager.java:162)   at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.<init>(RDBMSStoreManager.java:285)   at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor893.newInstance(null)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)  at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:606)     at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:301)   at org.datanucleus.NucleusContextHelper.createStoreManagerForProperties(NucleusContextHelper.java:133)  at org.datanucleus.PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.initialise(PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.java:422)     at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:817)  ... 134 more Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: Attempt to invoke the "HikariCP" plugin to create a ConnectionPool gave an error : Failed to initialize pool: **Could not connect to address=(host=consolidated-eastindia-prod-metastore.mysql.database.azure.com)(port=3306)(type=master) : Could not connect to consolidated-eastindia-prod-metastore.mysql.database.azure.com:3306 : Connection reset**   at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.generateDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:232)    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.initialiseDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:117)  at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.<init>(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:82)    ... 150 more Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: Failed to initialize pool: Could not connect to address=(host=consolidated-eastindia-prod-metastore.mysql.database.azure.com)(port=3306)(type=master) : Could not connect to consolidated-eastindia-prod-metastore.mysql.database.azure.com:3306 : Connection reset    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:512)     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:105)  at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:71)    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.connectionpool.HikariCPConnectionPoolFactory.createConnectionPool(HikariCPConnectionPoolFactory.java:176)    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.generateDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213)    ... 152 more Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: Could not connect to address=(host=consolidated-eastindia-prod-metastore.mysql.database.azure.com)(port=3306)(type=master) : Could not connect to consolidated-eastindia-prod-metastore.mysql.database.azure.com:3306 : Connection reset   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:73)     at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.create(ExceptionFactory.java:197)     at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1394)    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:635)   at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.newConnection(MariaDbConnection.java:150)     at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:89)  at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:95)  at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:101)     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:341)     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:506)     ... 156 more Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: Could not connect to consolidated-eastindia-prod-metastore.mysql.database.azure.com:3306 : Connection reset    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:73)     at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.create(ExceptionFactory.java:188)     at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.createConnection(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:575)    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1389)    ... 163 more Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: Connection reset   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)  at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.io.input.ReadAheadBufferedStream.fillBuffer(ReadAheadBufferedStream.java:131)  at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.io.input.ReadAheadBufferedStream.read(ReadAheadBufferedStream.java:104)    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.io.input.StandardPacketInputStream.getPacketArray(StandardPacketInputStream.java:247)  at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.io.input.StandardPacketInputStream.getPacket(StandardPacketInputStream.java:218)   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.com.read.ReadInitialHandShakePacket.<init>(ReadInitialHandShakePacket.java:89)   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.createConnection(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:527)

Answer (score 0):

The `ERROR java.lang.Exception: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient`
Is related to various possible reasons

- The Hive Metastore database is not available.
- The Hive Metastore database is not active.
- The configuration file for Hive is wrong.
- The `schematool` command hasn't been executed to set up the Hive Metastore database.
- The issue could be related to a firewall that was blocking us to perform certain commands.

You can resolve this by following the below:

**Step 1:** Make changes to the Hive settings.

**javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL:**
This setting tells Hive how to connect to its metadata storage (Metastore) using a JDBC URL. By default, it's set to `jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true.`

**javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName:**
This is about the JDBC driver class used for the Metastore database. The default is

```
org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.
```

**hive.metastore.warehouse.dir:**
This points to the directory where Hive stores its data warehouse.

**Step 2:** You can Backup and delete the Hive Metastore directory

```
mv -rf $HIVE_HOME/metastore_db $HIVE_HOME/metastore_db_bk
```

**Step 3:** Set up the Metastore database
Execute the schematool command to establish the Metastore database. run the following command:

```
schematool -initSchema -dbType derby
```

This command creates the Metastore database if it is not already there and sets up the necessary database structure.

**Reference:**

- [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35449274/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-org-apache-hadoop-hive-ql-meta) link for ERROR  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
- [Apache Hive: Resolve “unable to instantiate
  org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient”](https://ashwin.cloud/tutorials/apache-hive-resolve-sessionhivemetastoreclient/)

As you mentioned that you are trying to create catalog in the Azure databricks
I have tried the below ways  at my end and I am getting the below errors.

```
%sql
CREATE CATALOG IF NOT EXISTS Dileep_example_catalog;
```

**Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: [UC_NOT_ENABLED] Unity Catalog is not enabled on this cluster.**

```
spark.sql("CREATE CATALOG IF NOT EXISTS example")
```

**AnalysisException: [UC_NOT_ENABLED] Unity Catalog is not enabled on this cluster.**

```
%scala
spark.sql("CREATE CATALOG IF NOT EXISTS example")
```

**AnalysisException: [UC_NOT_ENABLED] Unity Catalog is not enabled on this cluster.**

Using the SQL editor:

```
CREATE CATALOG IF NOT EXISTS Dileep_example_catalog;
```

**[UC_NOT_ENABLED] Unity Catalog is not enabled on this cluster.**

***Note: creating catalog Applies to: Databricks SQL  Databricks Runtime 10.3 and above  Unity Catalog only***

If you are using the Unity catalog.
This article will help you Know more about [Creating a Unity Catalog metastore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/create-metastore)

I have tried the Below example to create databases Under default Hive metastore Catalog.

```
%sql
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS Database02;
USE Database02;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people (
  Name STRING,
  Age INT
);

%sql
CREATE TABLE default.people02
(
 Name STRING
);
```

[image]