# Hive configuration on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

I am trying to configure Hive 1.2.1 on Ubuntu 14.0.4.

I have set environment variables and created `hive-site.xml` and `hive-config.sh`. I have installed MYSQL and MySQL connector and put it in hive/lib folder. I have updated environment variables for HIVE_HOME and PATH, and HADOOP_HOME in `hive-confing.sh`.

hive-site.xml :

```
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore_db?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
</property>


<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
  <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
  <value>huser</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
  <value>huser</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>datanucleus.autoCreateSchema</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>datanucleus.fixedDatastore</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
```

Whenever I am trying to hit $hive command I am getting following exception:

```
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/home/huser/hive/lib/hive-common-1.2.1.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:677)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:621)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:520)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1523)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:86)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3005)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3024)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:503)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:426)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1521)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: The java type java.lang.Long (jdbc-type="", sql-type="") cant be mapped for this datastore. No mapping is available.
NestedThrowables:
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: The java type java.lang.Long (jdbc-type="", sql-type="") cant be mapped for this datastore. No mapping is available.
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:591)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:732)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:752)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setMetaStoreSchemaVersion(ObjectStore.java:6773)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.checkSchema(ObjectStore.java:6670)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.verifySchema(ObjectStore.java:6645)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:520)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.invoke(RawStoreProxy.java:114)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.verifySchema(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:572)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:624)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:461)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: The java type java.lang.Long (jdbc-type="", sql-type="") cant be mapped for this datastore. No mapping is available.
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.RDBMSMappingManager.getDatastoreMappingClass(RDBMSMappingManager.java:1215)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.RDBMSMappingManager.createDatastoreMapping(RDBMSMappingManager.java:1378)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.table.AbstractClassTable.addDatastoreId(AbstractClassTable.java:392)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.table.ClassTable.initializePK(ClassTable.java:1087)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.table.ClassTable.preInitialize(ClassTable.java:247)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager$ClassAdder.addClassTable(RDBMSStoreManager.java:3118)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager$ClassAdder.addClassTables(RDBMSStoreManager.java:2909)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager$ClassAdder.addClassTablesAndValidate(RDBMSStoreManager.java:3182)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager$ClassAdder.run(RDBMSStoreManager.java:2841)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.AbstractSchemaTransaction.execute(AbstractSchemaTransaction.java:122)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.addClasses(RDBMSStoreManager.java:1605)
    at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.addClass(AbstractStoreManager.java:954)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.getDatastoreClass(RDBMSStoreManager.java:679)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.getPropertiesForGenerator(RDBMSStoreManager.java:2045)
    at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.getStrategyValue(AbstractStoreManager.java:1365)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.newObjectId(ExecutionContextImpl.java:3827)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.setIdentity(JDOStateManager.java:2571)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.initialiseForPersistentNew(JDOStateManager.java:513)
    at org.datanucleus.state.ObjectProviderFactoryImpl.newForPersistentNew(ObjectProviderFactoryImpl.java:232)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.newObjectProviderForPersistentNew(ExecutionContextImpl.java:1414)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.persistObjectInternal(ExecutionContextImpl.java:2218)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.persistObjectWork(ExecutionContextImpl.java:2065)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.persistObject(ExecutionContextImpl.java:1913)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextThreadedImpl.persistObject(ExecutionContextThreadedImpl.java:217)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:727)
```

Comment: did you take a look at this link..? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22711364/java-lang-runtimeexceptionunable-to-instantiate-org-apache-hadoop-hive-metastor

Comment: Can you verify mysql username and password is huser?

Comment: Hi Dhruv, Yes I have verified password is entered correctly. I am suspecting that the issue is with : <property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore_db?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
</property>

Answer (score 0):

first you check mysql username and password matches to hive-site.xml file and  
you have not setting the warehouse directory path to hdfs, add this property to hive-site.xml.

```
<property>
    <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
    <value>/work/warehouse</value>
</property>
```

edit connection url value with port number as bellow

```
<name>javax.job.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hive-db?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
</property>
```

try now.

Answer (score 0):

Replace ***metastore_db*** by your current metastore_db name (default ***hive***):

```
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
</property>
```

It shoud work

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to the jdk version, use version under 1.8 may solve your problem.