# Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive

When run the spark example:

[spark-hive-tables](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables) , I get errors on hadoop UI

> User class threw exception: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient

and warning

> executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: An unknown (x.x.x.x:x) driver
>   disconnected.

but I have start hive metastore on my spark-yarn cluster, what should I do?

Comment: Please take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22711364/java-lang-runtimeexceptionunable-to-instantiate-org-apache-hadoop-hive-metastor

Comment: there is no metastore_db/*.lck under my spark directory ,hive.metastore.schema.verification is false, and i am using mysql

Answer (score 0):

It means you haven't started your Metastore service, so start you metastore service where you installed hive or in the remote if you have your metastore in remote.

To start metastore use `hive --service metastore`

what output you got after starting metastore service

Comment: i hava metastore running on each machine of my cluster
 -Xmx256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.log.dir=/data/opt/hadoop-2.6.0/logs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop.log -Dhadoop.home.dir=/data/opt/hadoop-2.6.0 -Dhadoop.id.str=root -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,console -Djava.library.path=/data/opt/hadoop-2.6.0/lib/native -Dhadoop.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xmx512m -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,NullAppender org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar /data/opt/apache-hive-1.2.1-bin/lib/hive-service-1.2.1.jar org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore

Answer (score 0):

I found out that i am using thrift server.after starting thrift by cmd
`/SPARKPATH/sbin/start-thriftserver.sh` ,here comes another error "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory" , which display errors like my title here. and it can be fixed by add `--jars /SPARKPATH/lib_managed/jars/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar,/SPARKPATH/lib_managed/jars/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar,/SPARKPATH/lib_managed/jars/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar`